# Does the direct usage of an indirectly referenced assembly always work in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

I thought in ASP.NET 5 you'd have to rely on nuget packages, or the [bin wrapper](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#bin-syntax-wrapping-a-dll) (which never worked for me btw.) if you want to reference an assembly that does not come from a project that is in the same solution as the web/dnx project.

Now I have an ASP.NET 5 RC1 project where I reference a 4.5.1 standard class library project from the same solution like this:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "MyProject.Utilities": "1.0.0-*"
    }
  }
}
```

(I don't use "dnxcore50": { })

Everything gets wrapped as expected, MyProjects.Utilities and its required assemblies. What I think is funny is that now in my web project I cannot only use MyProject.Utilities but also all the assemblies MyProject.Utilities references. It doesn't matter if I referenced the assembly via nuget from MyProject.Utilities or if I added an assembly via Add Reference -> Browse from MyProject.Utilities. I can use both types of indirectly referenced assemblies directly in my web project just so out of the box.

I think this is great, will this stay this way? Was this always meant to work this way?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand correctly your problem. Do you included the path to the class library project in the `global.json`, which exist typically in the directory which is parent for your both projects (in the solution folder)? It should contains `"projects": [ "MyProject.Utilities", "MyProject.Main" ]`. If both `MyProject.Utilities` and your main project are inside of `src` directory, then you can have `"projects": [ "src" ]`.

Comment: @Oleg I never touched global.json, yes it contains `"projects": [ "src" ]` but not `MyProject...`. I added the reference to `"MyProject.Utilities"` via "Add Reference..." -> "Projects". I'm just wondering why I can use all the types from the wrapped assemblies in my web project although most of those types aren't in assemblies that are direct dependencies of my web project.

Comment: You wrote already that you used "Add Reference -> Browse" to add the MyProject.Utilities project, but you didn't described the structure of the directories of your solution. Moreover, ASP.NET 5 is not final and you must be aware, that not all works. The new structure structure should be: solution folder with `global.json`, which contains `"projects"` with the list of relative or absolute path to the folders, which contains projects. One can includes `NuGet.Config` file in solution level too. Could you add the folder with `"MyProject.Utilities"` or its parent folder to `"projects"`?

Comment: @Oleg Yes I have this structure and everything works. My mainpoint is that I want to know if using indirect dependencies directly from the web project will always work in the future (e.g. with future versions of ASP.NET 5) just like it does now.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand now you current problem at all. Do you have a problem now or not? Nobody can say you nothing exactly about "the future". A lot of things will be changed between beta versions and even between RC1 and RC2. A lot of assembles and the names of classes will be renamed. Look at [the announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/labels/Announcement) for example. You should be ready for breaking changes if you work with not released product.

Comment: @Oleg No, I don't have a problem, it's a question. If I now rely on the behavior described by me  (and I already do to some extent)  then I will have a problem in the future if this behavior changes because then I'd have to write my own wrapper classes and put them in `MyProject.Utilities` for many things I now use directly in the web project. Sorry if I was misleading.

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't continue to work. In fact it stopped working with ASP.NET core RC 2. Dependencies now have to be specified explicityla as NuGet packages in the web project in order to use them from there.

Visual Studio 15 will probably allow to reference local dlls without the need for packages just like non core projets though.